# Cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:443] for HAproxy

Tags: ssl, websocket, load-balancing, haproxy

I have made the following ha-proxy configuration and have recieved the following error while HAProxy restart:

HAproxy Config

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    tcp
        option  tcplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        timeout client 3h
        timeout server 3h
        timeout connect  5000


frontend fe_websockets
        bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /home/test/Documents/test3.pem
        mode tcp
        log global
        option tcplog
        timeout client 3600s
        backlog 4096
        maxconn 50000
        default_backend be_nywebsockets

backend be_nywebsockets
        mode  tcp
        option log-health-checks
        option redispatch
        option tcplog
        balance roundrobin
        server web1 localhost:8443 check
       # server web2 localhost:8081 check
        timeout connect 1s
        timeout queue 5s
        timeout server 3600s
```

Why does HAProxy doesnt allow to bind 443 to some server port?
I have followed the configuration specified in the following link:
https://gist.github.com/allanparsons/6076098
[ALERT] 101/231920 (8356) : Starting frontend fe_websockets: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:443]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, port 443 is already in use by another process. Check using `netstat` if you have existing processes in the haproxy box already bound to it.